# Customization of UISearchBar in iOS 8.1 using Swift

Tags: swift, ios8.1

I want to customize in the UISearchBar the following things maninly, if it's possible to do of course :

- Change the color of the icon for the search icon by default.
- Change the orientation of the icon to the right instead of the left.
- Change the font size and font type of the text inserted to find.

The below image it's an example of the two first question using the same icon of the SDK.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

PD : Please refer only to Swift.

Answer (score 0):

- SWIFT
- IOS 8

1) find a good icon, the color you want, and set it using .setImage

```
// images
self.setImage(UIImage(named: "Search-white"), forSearchBarIcon: UISearchBarIcon.Search, state: UIControlState.Normal)
```

3) For me, this worked using a recursive function to find the actual textfield.

```
extension UIView {

func recursive_applyTheme_Search(
    #dynamicTextStyle: NSString,
    bgColor: UIColor,
    cursorColor: UIColor,
    textColor: UIColor,
    placeholderTextColor: UIColor,
    borderColor: UIColor,
    borderWidth: CGFloat,
    cornerRadius: CGFloat) {

    for subview in self.subviews
    {
        if subview is UITextField {

            (subview as! UITextField).applyThemeForSearchBar(
                dynamicTextStyle: dynamicTextStyle,
                bgColor: bgColor,
                cursorColor: cursorColor,
                textColor: textColor,
                placeholderTextColor: placeholderTextColor,
                borderColor: borderColor,
                borderWidth: borderWidth,
                cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
        }
        else { subview.recursive_applyTheme_Search(
                dynamicTextStyle: dynamicTextStyle,
                bgColor: bgColor,
                cursorColor: cursorColor,
                textColor: textColor,
                placeholderTextColor: placeholderTextColor,
                borderColor: borderColor,
                borderWidth: borderWidth,
                cornerRadius: cornerRadius) }
    }

}
}
```